# How long should it take to build a single column index in MySQL for a 100K row table?

Tags: mysql, ddl

I have been trying to create an index on a varchar(20) column with 100K rows, and it's been running for 30 minutes so far.  On an 8 core i7 processor with 16GB of memory and an SSD drive, I just don't understand what's taking it so long.

Any ideas?  I'm a bit new to MySQL, but this is just a basic vanilla index on a relatively small table.  The one other index on the same table took only a few seconds to generate.

How does one debug this sort of thing in MySQL?

Comment: What sort of index, 'unique'? How variable is the data? If not a unique index and a lot of the values are the same then it could take a while. Actually, if the index is not very selective then it may not be worth having. Other things to check: How fragmented is the disk and available space.

Comment: Normal non-unique index, but few duplicates.  Disk is freshly formated as this is a new LAMP install on the box.

Comment: Internet Search: 'mysql index create takes a long time' return some interesting links. example: [adding an index is very slow...](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/10732/adding-an-index-very-slow-is-there-a-mysql-cmd-to-get-an-eta-or-show-progress)

Comment: I did that, but these people are all talking about Millions of rows.  My 100K row table should have been done in minutes.  It is almost an hour now and still running...

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that the default Ubuntu server LAMP install of MySQL has incredibly low memory allocated, requiring an enormous amount of disk swapping, even on machines that have obvious excess memory.

Please note that I did not experiment to see which setting(s) solved the issue, but the commands I was running on 100K rows, which previously ran for hours, now only take seconds.

```
[mysqld]
key_buffer_size         = 256M
max_allowed_packet      = 16M

# Added
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 2G
innodb_log_buffer_size  = 64M
innodb_log_file_size    = 64M
skip_name_resolve

query_cache_limit       = 16M
query_cache_size        = 64M
```

Answer (score 0):

What's the total size in memory of the table? If it's big enough that you're getting a lot of hard drive calls, it could still take a while. Also, is your site live while you're doing this?

As far as debugging goes, you could check your SQL process on the system to see how many resources it's using.

Finally, have you looked at creating a multi-column index rather than two single-column indexes?

Comment: Data length is 22609920. small.  ...and the box is running a fresh LAMP installation.  CPU on the box is at 10%.